# HTML offline file readonly on network computer if already opened by some user

Tags: javascript, html, offline

I developed an offline HTML form which is used to store on a network computer. It contains a save draft button which creates the copy of the form with data filled by the user. Now the issue is when two users simultaneously opened the file the saved draft contains the data of the users who filled it last.

My idea is to make the offline HTML file read-only when it is already accessing from the server by any of the users.

Comment: So if just one user opens the file, lock it until he saves draft? This is what you want?

Comment: Do you use any database?

Comment: I am not sure if the OS (Windows / Linux) provides any help in getting an exclusive lock on a file. I think it depends more on the program opening the file to open it in an exclusive mode. Meaning if you don't control the tool used to edit the file, you may need to look for a different alternative.

Comment: @AlbertoLópezPérez right

Comment: @RA'sal unfortuntely not. As the application is an standalone offline HTML form using javascript and jquery

Answer (score 0):

To control this you can:

- Create a secondary file where you store a flag (variable) that will contain a true or a false. So, before reading the file that contains all the data, read this file first and if this file contains a 1 (true or whatever) display "file is locked, try again later" or something similar.
- You can also setup this flag [with a cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie). Then you do the same as the previous option. Checking the flag value.

Remember always to set it up to 0 when you finish editing it so after processing the file you can open it again.